# UDP buffer overrun and old datagram clearing

Tags: networking, socket, udp, sysctl

I am reading UDP datagrams on a linux server at 700,000 per second from HDL32 LIDAR system. Interface is ipv4. Sockets are set to SOREUSADDR.  I turn on the LIDAR,  start up socket program, it started reading datagrams.  It ran for about 4 hours then I turned off program reading while LIDAR was still operating.

LIDAR is turned off. I run program  it's reading old packets.  Turn Linux off, restart, it's still reading packets.  Service network restart; still reading old packets.

It's impressive to say the least but...

Question 1; how do I tell Linux to clear old UDP datagrams ? Use sysctl? Do I clear ipv4.udp_mem?

Question 2. In the future, what startup routine should I adopt to make sure old data is off the stack?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to clear the UDP receive buffer?